# Compiling googletest with clang on Windows

Tags: c++, clang, googletest

I am trying to compile googletest on Windows using clang 6.0.1. There is a basic makefile provided which already compiles the libraries but fails at linking the examples. The linker complains about 7 unresolved symbols for file handling like, fclose, fopen, creat.

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: read
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: close
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: write
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: fdopen
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: dup
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: creat
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: error: gtest_main.lib(gtest-all.o): undefined symbol: dup2
```

Using Visual Studio, it compiles and links without any problem. I used the command-line from MSVC and adapted it, but still clang doesn't link.
Here is the adapted makefile I am using:

```
CXX = clang++
AR = llvm-ar
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include -D"WIN32" -D"WINDOWS" -D"_WINDOWS" -D"_WIN32" -D"STRICT" -D"WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" -D"GTEST_HAS_PTHREAD"=0 -D"_HAS_EXCEPTIONS"=1
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra

LINKFLAGS = -l"kernel32.lib" -l"user32.lib" -l"gdi32.lib" -l"winspool.lib" -l"shell32.lib" -l"ole32.lib" -l"oleaut32.lib" -l"uuid.lib" -l"comdlg32.lib" -l"advapi32.lib" -l"libucrt.lib" -l"libcmt.lib" -l"msvcrt.lib" -l"libvcruntime.lib" -l"libcpmt.lib"
gtest.lib : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
sample1_unittest.exe : sample1.o sample1_unittest.o gtest_main.lib
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -fuse-ld=lld -v $^ -o $@
```

When using link.exe instead of lld, the same error occur, but when compiling in MSVC it works well. So I guess I just translated an option of the MS tools wrongly or missed an library. Are there any hints or has someone already compiled googletest with clang on Windows?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: Unlukily not, we went to a gcc/migw based build for tests.